# What is the meaning of integral notation with function as differential?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the meaning of this integral notation where a function evaluated at point c is the differential and how does it differ from a regular integral that has a variable as differential?

$$\int u(o)\, dF(o)$$ vs. $$\int u(o)\, do$$

In this example, function $F$ is a probability distribution over $o$.

Comment: This either refers to integrals over differential forms or to the Stieltjes-Integral. See [wiki/Stieltjes Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_integral#Definition) and [wiki/Differential Form#Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Integration). There are also generalisations, I think. Oh, in the case that $F$ is a probability distribution, this also refers to integration with respect to the measure induced by $F$.

Comment: It could mean the following
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dg(x) = \int_a^b f(x)g'(x)dx
$$
if $F$ is a c.d.f then $F'$ is a p.d.f so it is kind of like a weight function.

Comment: Thanks @k.stm, it makes sense it is indeed a Stieltjes integral.

Comment: Thanks, @Benedict W. J. Irwin, that's how it is calculated, thanks for the help.

Comment: Either @BenedictW.J.Irwin or the other commenters may want to post an answer to this question.